# Refer classes from module of wildfly in war file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I want to remove classes folder from WAR files's WEB-INF folder and refer the same from jar file which is loaded as an module of wildfly server.
So I have created and module  in `wildfly-home/modules/com/mypackage/main` jar and module.xml of module name `"com.mypackage"`
and added the same in manifest.mf file of war

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Dependencies: com.mypackage
```

But this doesn't work.

Server : wildfly 8.2

Comment: I'd advise using the `module add` CLI command to assist with installing the module. If you'd rather not use that verify your path, should be module*s*, and ensure the correctness of your module.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory is incorrect. With wildfly you have to put the module in:

```
{wildfly-home}/modules/system/layers/base
```

Comment: It was meant to be an answer. Edited text to indicate such.

Comment: Modules can be placed in `modules/` or `modules/system/layers/base`. The `module add` CLI command places them in the `modules/` directory by default.

Comment: I agree that you should be able to place it there, but I have not been able to get this to work in WildFly 9. I can't find any info as to why.

Comment: nevermind, I got it working after using the cli, I don't know why it was failing before.